# How to make the Button appear on the right side of a TitledPane JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

I have managed to place a Button inside a TitledPane using setGraphic but I want it to be located on the right side; here is the code:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Accordion acordion = new Accordion();

    TitledPane tp1 = new TitledPane();

    Button b1 = new Button();

    b1.setText("X");

    tp1.setGraphic(b1);

    acordion.getPanes().addAll(tp1);

    Scene scene = new Scene(acordion, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

[The Button should be located on the right but I do not know how to do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WciN.png)

[image]

Comment: Try an `HBox`. Add two `Buttons` to it. The first `Button` should be set to `HBox.AlwaysGrow(). The second `Button` is the one you are currently using. Make the first `Button` invisible. Finally, add the `HBox` to the `TitledPane` graphic. I am thinking this should work, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: If you add a button only as invisible placeholder you don't need a button: Using `Region` is sufficient...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `alignment` property of `TitledPane` to `CENTER_RIGHT`:

```
tp1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
```